How to load a URDF file in aframe?
I am trying to load a URDF file in aframe scene to visualize it on VR. The code for aframe component is:
<script type="importmap"> { "imports": {
                    "urdf-loader":  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/urdf-loader@0.12.1/umd/URDFLoader.js",
                    "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/"
                } }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
      import 'urdf-loader';
      import {
        STLLoader
      } from 'three/addons/loaders/STLLoader';
      import {
        WebGLRenderer,
        Mesh,
        MathUtils,
        Bone,
        Vector3
      } from 'three';
      AFRAME.registerComponent('load-panda-urdf', {
        init: function() {
          const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
          const loader = new URDFLoader(manager);
          loader.load('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanfordASL/PandaRobot.jl/master/deps/Panda/panda.urdf', // The path to the URDF within the package OR absolute
            robot => {
              // The robot is loaded!
              this.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(robot);
            });
        },
      })
    </script>

I get these warnings
URDFLoader: Could not load model at /Panda/meshes/collision/link0.obj.
No loader available

URDFLoader: Could not load model at /Panda/meshes/collision/link1.obj.

URDFLoader: Could not load model at /Panda/meshes/collision/link2.obj.

URDFLoader: Could not load model at /Panda/meshes/collision/link3.obj.

URDFLoader: Could not load model at /Panda/meshes/collision/link4.obj.

I went through the documentation of the urdf-loaders project on github but couldn't find any fix for this. How do I fix this?
PS:
This is the jsfiddle to try the code
